# How to display uploaded image file in grid from a folder in the root?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Aspx.vb code which i am using to save data in a  folder.

```
Try
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    Dim hfc As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files
    Dim PathName As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To hfc.Count - 1
        Dim hpf As HttpPostedFile = hfc(i)

        If hpf.ContentLength > 0 Then
            PathName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName)
            Dim BookingNumber As String = objWHParent.WHImageTabList.ToList().Item(i).BookingNumber
            Dim FileName As String = BookingNumber + "_WRH_" + (i.ToString()) + PathName
            hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImages\") & FileName)


            objWHParent.WHImageTabList.ToList().Item(i).FilePath = FileName
            objWHParent.WHImageTabList.ToList().Item(i).Flag = "Warehouse"
        End If
    Next
Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
    Throw
End Try
```

After uploading i want to display each image uploaded behind the browse button in the grid

Comment: @RameshRajendran ?! Then why are you commenting here? SO is not a forum to share your "opinions" (much less hate-based ones). For example, if I would share my views, I would have said that hate is a synonym of ignorance; and that VB.NET and C# are basically the same; and that, actually speaking, the pure .NET language is VB (which is the Microsoft language), that C# is a recent creation with the sole purpose of compensating irrational hates and bringing developers to .NET :)

Comment: @son, please explain further what you are trying to do.. You say you want to upload "the" image, but what I see in your code, you're accepting multiple files.

Comment: @ André Figueiredo: I want to display each image in the grid at respective uploaded row

Answer (score 1):

You need to add image control on gridview and give URL from your Data source. Please see below code for reference:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvFolder"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText = "Image Name" DataField="ImageName" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageURL") %>'Height="150px" Width="150px"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```